# EAS iOS build fails with Fastlane error: “error extracting version from module interface”

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, eas

- Managed Workflow
- `eas-cli` version is `0.60.0`

**Goal**: embed third-party native library as `npm` package to a managed Expo project.

**What I have**: the library provided by vendor as a `.xcframework` for iOS (Swift) and `.aab` file for Android.

**What I did**:

- generated a template for custom React Native library using `npx create-react-native-library` command.
- added `.aab` and `.xcframework` files to appropriate folders.
- provided implementation in `Java` and `Swift` for both platforms.
- built library locally.
- prior to publish my RN package to a private GH repo I tested library in `example` app which was generated by `create-react-native-library`, to ensure that everything works right.
- example app works as expected.
- published RN package to a repo and installed it into my Expo project.
- **STUCK ON THIS STEP**: I try to build custom dev client using `eas build` command. And the build fails.

```
❌  (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/app/node_modules/@bridgemoney/react-native-sardine/ios/ReactNativeSardine.swift:2:8)

  1 | import Foundation
> 2 | import MobileIntelligence
    |        ^ error extracting version from module interface
  3 | 
  4 | @objc(ReactNativeSardine)
  5 | class ReactNativeSardine: RCTEventEmitter {

❌  (/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BridgeGo-cyholdfvmztnmecppglqrfgqcshq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BridgeGo/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/bridgemoney-react-native-sardine/MobileIntelligence.framework/Modules/MobileIntelligence.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:1:1)

> 1 | // swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
    | ^ error extracting version from module interface
  2 | // swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)
  3 | // swift-module-flags: -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -enable-objc-interop -enable-library-evolution -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -module-name MobileIntelligence
  4 | import AdSupport
```

```
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/expo/workingdir/build/app/node_modules/@bridgemoney/react-native-sardine/ios/ReactNativeSardine.swift (in target 'bridgemoney-react-native-sardine' from project 'Pods')
▸   EmitSwiftModule normal arm64 (in target 'bridgemoney-react-native-sardine' from project 'Pods')
▸   CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'bridgemoney-react-native-sardine' from project 'Pods')
▸ (3 failures)
```

Do anyone know what does this mean and how to fix this?

More context:

- I use `latest` image for iOS in `eas.json` file with XCode 13.4 and Swift 5.6.1
- example RN app compiles and works as expected with my custom library. On my local Mac I use XCode 13.4.1 and Swift 5.6.1 as well.